# Proving that the sequence terms ${T_{n+1}}=T_n^2-T_n+1$ are relatively prime

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, induction

Given that $T_1=2$ and ${T_{n+1}}=T_n^2-T_n+1$, $n>0$.

prove that $T_n$ and $T_m$ are relatively prime whenever $n \neq m$

I tried by calculating the first few terms in the sequence, but I couldn't recognize a pattren. I am also thinking of doing an induction proof on $k$, where  $n+m=k$. But don't have idea where to start.

Any hits or solution will be appreciated

Comment: If you mean $T_{n+1}=T_n^2-T_n+1$, you can prove, by induction on $k$, that $T_{n+k}\equiv 1 \pmod{T_n}$

Comment: My apologies, I have miss written the question

Comment: Thanks, Naruki. I found the solution, your hint was really helpful. Should I post a solution, on the answer section?

Comment: Yes, go ahead (if you want me to write one and earn some reputation that's also fine, but by writing yourself you can practice your writing and save my time).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Naruki Masuda hint, I was able to answer the question.

Prove by induction

Base Case : Since  $T_{n+1}=T_n^2-T_n+1$

Then $T_{n+1}\equiv 1 \pmod{T_n}$

Induction hypothesis : assume it's true for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$

$T_{n+k}\equiv 1 \pmod{T_n}$
Then $T_{n+k+1}={T_{n+k}}^2-T_{n+k}+1\equiv 1^2-1+1=1\pmod{T_n}$

Thus by mathematical induction, it's true for all elements in this sequence that $T_n$ and $T_m$ are relatively prime whenever $n \neq m$

Comment: Sorry, I miss wrote the name. Thanks brother, for your comment.

Comment: Don’t worry, I won’t get upset about that. For completeness, you should write the claim you proved in your solution. This is a good example of the fact that it’s sometimes easier to prove a stronger statement.

Comment: Thanks Naruki, for your help appreciated